# Why is return coming back as undefined?

Tags: javascript, return

In this code I have written, y comes back as undefined. I've looked everywhere I can think of to figure out what I did wrong, but as far as I can tell it's correctly written. It's supposed to come back as 00085.

```
function ab()
{
  var x = 85 + '';
  var y = AddCorrect(x);
}

function AddCorrect(add)
{
  if (add.length < 5)
  {
    var corrected = '0' + add;
    AddCorrect(corrected);
  }
  else
  {
    return add;
  }
}
```

Comment: `return AddCorrect(corrected);`

Comment: Okay I guess that makes sense. If its a repeat, should I just delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You pass a number but your function expect a string (you're checking `add.length`). You have also to return something inside `if (add.length < 5)`:

```js
function ab()
{
  var x = 85;
  var y = AddCorrect(x);   // <-- x is a number
  console.log(y);
}

function AddCorrect(add)
{
  add = '' + add;     // <--- Convert the number to string
  
  if (add.length < 5)  // <--- so you can check the length
  {
    var corrected = '0' + add;
    return AddCorrect(corrected); // <--- return here
  }
  else
  {
    return add;
  }
}

ab();
```